# Conditional proxy_intercept_errors directive

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Hi I have the following proxy config:

```
    location / {
        proxy_pass        http://localhost:8080/;
        proxy_set_header  Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto  https;
        if($request_filename ~* "^api/"){
             proxy_intercept_errors on;
        }
    }
```

I'm not yet entirely sure yet if the if condition is correct but I would like to disable the proxy_intercept_errors for all the calls to /api location. For any other they should be intercepted.

How can I make such an exclude without defining an additional location block?

With this if condition I'm getting the following error:

```
nginx: [emerg] "proxy_intercept_errors" directive is not allowed here
```

Comment: You can't `proxy_intercept_errors` in a "if in location" level. It will need to be a different location block. Why don't you want a different location block?

Comment: @Drifter104 I'm trying to avoid duplication. I have to copy the whole block and just add that one directive with proper location match.